I got a message error by creating the SQL Agent Job
The script for creating SQL Agent-Jobs is not working.
I created a table for later recovery of the agent job. And one script for restoring if one is accidentally deleted.
Unfortunately I get an error message that a procedure is being executed in the background and two parameters are missing.
Here is error message

Procedure or function 'sp_verify_category_identifiers' expects parameter '@category_name', which was not supplied.

enter image description here
I looked at this procedure and saw that this procedure has 4 parameters. I have no idea how I can manage these parameters
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_verify_category_identifiers]
    @name_of_name_parameter [varchar](60),
    @name_of_id_parameter [varchar](60),
    @category_name [sysname] OUTPUT,
    @category_id [INT] OUTPUT

Here is my code
USE msdb;
GO

DECLARE @job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @originating_server_id INT,
    @job_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @owner_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @job_enabled BIT,
    @job_description NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @job_start_step_id INT,
    @job_category_id INT,
    @job_owner_sid VARBINARY(85),
    @notify_level_eventlog INT,
    @notify_level_email INT,
    @notify_level_netsend INT,
    @notify_level_page INT,
    @notify_email_operator_id INT,
    @notify_netsend_operator_id INT,
    @notify_page_operator_id INT,
    @delete_level INT,
    @job_date_created DATETIME,
    @job_date_modified DATETIME,
    @job_version_number INT,
    @schedule_id INT,
    @schedule_next_run_date INT,
    @step_id INT,
    @step_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @step_subsystem NVARCHAR(128),
    @step_command NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @step_flags INT,
    @step_additional_parameters NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @step_cmdexec_success_code INT,
    @step_on_success_action INT,
    @step_on_success_step_id INT,
    @step_on_fail_action INT,
    @step_on_fail_step_id INT,
    @step_server NVARCHAR(128),
    @step_database_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @step_database_user_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @step_retry_attempts INT,
    @step_retry_interval INT,
    @step_os_run_priority INT,
    @step_output_file_name NVARCHAR(4000),
    @step_last_run_outcome INT,
    @step_last_run_duration INT,
    @step_last_run_retries INT,
    @step_last_run_date INT,
    @step_last_run_time INT,
    @step_proxy_id INT,
    @category_id INT,
    @category_class INT,
    @category_type INT,
    @category_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @server_id INT,
    @server_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @server_last_run_outcome INT,
    @last_outcome_message NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @server_last_run_date INT,
    @server_last_run_time INT,
    @server_last_run_duration INT,
    @schedule_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @schedule_freq_type INT,
    @schedule_originating_server_id INT,
    @schedule_owner_sid VARBINARY(85),
    @schedule_enabled BIT,
    @schedule_freq_interval INT,
    @schedule_freq_subday_type INT,
    @schedule_freq_subday_interval INT,
    @schedule_freq_relative_interval INT,
    @schedule_freq_recurrence_factor INT,
    @schedule_date_created DATETIME,
    @schedule_date_modified DATETIME,
    @schedule_active_start_date INT,
    @schedule_active_end_date INT,
    @schedule_active_start_time INT,
    @schedule_active_end_time INT,
    @operator_id INT,
    @operator_name NVARCHAR(128),
    @op_email_address  NVARCHAR(128),
    @op_notify_page_operator_name  NVARCHAR(128),
    @alerts_id INT,
    @alerts_name NVARCHAR(128) ,
    @alert_has_notifications INT,
    @alerts_database_name NVARCHAR(512),
    @message_id INT,
    @severity INT,
    @delay_between_responses INT

DECLARE job_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT job_id, originating_server_id, job_name,owner_name, job_enabled, job_description, job_start_step_id,   job_category_id, job_owner_sid, notify_level_eventlog, notify_level_email, notify_level_netsend, notify_level_page, notify_email_operator_id, notify_netsend_operator_id, notify_page_operator_id, delete_level, job_date_created, job_date_modified, job_version_number, schedule_id , schedule_next_run_date, step_id, step_name, step_subsystem, step_command, step_flags, step_additional_parameters, step_cmdexec_success_code, step_on_success_action, step_on_success_step_id, step_on_fail_action, step_on_fail_step_id, step_server, step_database_name, step_database_user_name, step_retry_attempts, step_retry_interval, step_os_run_priority, step_output_file_name, step_last_run_outcome, step_last_run_duration, step_last_run_retries, step_last_run_date, step_last_run_time, step_proxy_id, category_id, category_class, category_type, category_name, server_id, server_name, server_last_run_outcome, last_outcome_message,server_last_run_date, server_last_run_time, server_last_run_duration, schedule_name, schedule_freq_type, schedule_originating_server_id, schedule_owner_sid, schedule_enabled, schedule_freq_interval,@schedule_freq_subday_type, schedule_freq_subday_interval, schedule_freq_relative_interval, schedule_freq_recurrence_factor, schedule_date_created, schedule_date_modified, schedule_active_start_date, schedule_active_end_date, schedule_active_start_time, schedule_active_end_time, operator_id, operator_name, op_email_address, op_notify_page_operator_name, alerts_id, alerts_name, alert_has_notifications, alerts_database_name, message_id, severity,delay_between_responses

FROM 
    [Test_DB1].[dbo].[JobAgentRestore];

OPEN job_cursor;

     FETCH NEXT FROM job_cursor INTO @job_id, @originating_server_id, @job_name, @owner_name,  @job_enabled, @job_description, @job_start_step_id, @job_category_id, @job_owner_sid, @notify_level_eventlog, @notify_level_email, @notify_level_netsend, @notify_level_page, @notify_email_operator_id, @notify_netsend_operator_id, @notify_page_operator_id, @delete_level, @job_date_created, @job_date_modified, @job_version_number, @schedule_id, @schedule_next_run_date, @step_id, @step_name, @step_subsystem, @step_command, @step_flags, @step_additional_parameters, @step_cmdexec_success_code, @step_on_success_action, @step_on_success_step_id, @step_on_fail_action, @step_on_fail_step_id, @step_server, @step_database_name, @step_database_user_name, @step_retry_attempts, @step_retry_interval, @step_os_run_priority, @step_output_file_name, @step_last_run_outcome, @step_last_run_duration, @step_last_run_retries, @step_last_run_date, @step_last_run_time, @step_proxy_id, @category_id, @category_class, @category_type, @category_name, @server_id, @server_name, @server_last_run_outcome, @last_outcome_message, @server_last_run_date, @server_last_run_time, @server_last_run_duration, @schedule_name, @schedule_freq_type, @schedule_originating_server_id, @schedule_owner_sid, @schedule_enabled, @schedule_freq_interval, @schedule_freq_subday_type, @schedule_freq_subday_interval, @schedule_freq_relative_interval, @schedule_freq_recurrence_factor, @schedule_date_created, @schedule_date_modified, @schedule_active_start_date, @schedule_active_end_date, @schedule_active_start_time, @schedule_active_end_time, @operator_id, @operator_name, @op_email_address, @op_notify_page_operator_name, @alerts_id, @alerts_name, @alert_has_notifications, @alerts_database_name, @message_id, @severity, @delay_between_responses


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print  @job_owner_sid;
    print 'owner name:' + @owner_name; 
    --Create job if not existing
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name =@job_name)
    BEGIN
        print  @job_owner_sid;
    print 'owner name:' + @owner_name;
    SELECT @server_name = server_name FROM [Test_DB1].[dbo].[JobAgentRestore] where server_id = @server_id
    print  @server_name ;

    Print ' sp_add_job'
    Print 'category @category_name: ' + @category_name
    PRINT '@category_id: ' + CAST(@category_id AS NVARCHAR(128));
    print 'owner name:' + @owner_name;

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job    
            @job_name = @job_name,
            @enabled = @job_enabled,
            @description = @job_description,
            @start_step_id = @job_start_step_id,
            @category_id = @job_category_id,
            @category_name = @category_name,
            @notify_level_eventlog = @notify_level_eventlog,
            @notify_level_email = @notify_level_email,
            @notify_level_netsend = @notify_level_netsend,
            @notify_level_page = @notify_level_page,
            @delete_level = @delete_level,
            @owner_login_name = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @owner_name) + ',
            @notify_email_operator_name=@operator_name, 
            @notify_page_operator_name=@op_notify_page_operator_name,
            @job_id = @job_id OUTPUT

        Print ' sp_add_job ende'
        Print ' sp_add_jobserver'
        
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name= @job_name, @server_name=@server_name
        Print ' sp_add_jobserver ende'
        Print ' sp_add_jobstep'
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name = @job_name, 
            @step_name = @step_name, 
            @step_id = @step_id, 
            @cmdexec_success_code = @step_cmdexec_success_code, 
            @on_success_action = @step_on_success_action, 
            @on_fail_action = @step_on_fail_action, 
            @retry_attempts = @step_retry_attempts, 
            @retry_interval = @step_retry_attempts, 
            @os_run_priority = @step_os_run_priority, 
            @subsystem = @step_subsystem, 
            @command = @step_command, 
            @database_name = @step_database_name,
            @flags=@step_flags
        
        Print 'sp_add_jobstep end';

        Print 'sp_update_job';
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=@job_name, 
        @enabled=@job_enabled, 
            @start_step_id = @job_start_step_id, 
            @notify_level_eventlog=@notify_level_eventlog, 
            @notify_level_email=@notify_level_email, 
            @notify_level_page=@notify_level_page, 
            @delete_level=@delete_level,
            @description=@job_description, 
            @category_name=@category_name, 
            @owner_login_name = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @owner_name) + ', 
            @notify_email_operator_name=@operator_name, 
            @notify_page_operator_name=@op_notify_page_operator_name
        Print ' sp_update_job end'

        -- Create the job schedule
        Print ' sp_add_jobschedule'
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
            @job_id = @job_id,
            @name = @schedule_name, 
            @freq_type = @schedule_freq_type, 
            @freq_interval = @schedule_freq_interval,
            @active_start_time = @schedule_active_start_time,
            @active_end_time = @schedule_active_end_time,
            @active_start_date = @schedule_active_start_date; 
        Print ' sp_add_jobschedule ende'

        Print ' sp_attach_schedule'
        EXEC sp_attach_schedule  
            @job_name = @job_name,
            @schedule_name = @schedule_name;
    Print ' sp_attach_schedule ende'

    Print ' sp_add_alert'
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=@alerts_name, 
            @message_id=@message_id, 
            @severity=@severity, 
            @enabled=@job_enabled, 
            @delay_between_responses=@delay_between_responses, 
            @include_event_description_in=0
        Print ' sp_add_alert end'
        
        Print ' sp_start_job'
    
        -- Starting the job
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name;
        Print ' sp_start_job end'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Job already exists: ' + @job_name;
    END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM job_cursor INTO @job_id, @originating_server_id, @job_name, @owner_name, @job_enabled, @job_description, @job_start_step_id, @job_category_id, @job_owner_sid, @notify_level_eventlog, @notify_level_email, @notify_level_netsend, @notify_level_page, @notify_email_operator_id, @notify_netsend_operator_id, @notify_page_operator_id, @delete_level, @job_date_created, @job_date_modified, @job_version_number, @schedule_id, @schedule_next_run_date, @step_id, @step_name, @step_subsystem, @step_command, @step_flags, @step_additional_parameters, @step_cmdexec_success_code, @step_on_success_action, @step_on_success_step_id, @step_on_fail_action, @step_on_fail_step_id, @step_server, @step_database_name, @step_database_user_name, @step_retry_attempts, @step_retry_interval, @step_os_run_priority, @step_output_file_name, @step_last_run_outcome, @step_last_run_duration, 
@step_last_run_retries, @step_last_run_date, @step_last_run_time, @step_proxy_id, @category_id, @category_class, @category_type, @category_name, @server_id, @server_name, @server_last_run_outcome, @last_outcome_message, @server_last_run_date, @server_last_run_time, @server_last_run_duration, @schedule_name, @schedule_freq_type, @schedule_originating_server_id, @schedule_owner_sid, @schedule_enabled, @schedule_freq_interval, @schedule_freq_subday_type, @schedule_freq_subday_interval, @schedule_freq_relative_interval, @schedule_freq_recurrence_factor, @schedule_date_created, @schedule_date_modified, @schedule_active_start_date, @schedule_active_end_date, @schedule_active_start_time, @schedule_active_end_time, @operator_id, @operator_name, @op_email_address, @op_notify_page_operator_name, @alerts_id, @alerts_name, @alert_has_notifications, @alerts_database_name, @message_id, @severity, @delay_between_responses

END;

CLOSE job_cursor;
DEALLOCATE job_cursor;

Here is code for the restore table
-- Using the msdb database
USE msdb;
GO

-- Step 1: Check whether the JobData table exists and delete it if necessary
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Test_DB1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'JobAgentRestore')
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [Test_DB1].dbo.JobAgentRestore;
    END;

-- Step 2: Create the JobData table if it does not exist
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Test_DB1].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'JobAgentRestore')
    BEGIN
        -- Create a table to store data for later job agent recovery
        CREATE TABLE [Test_DB1].dbo.JobAgentRestore (
            job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            originating_server_id INT,
            job_name NVARCHAR(128),
            owner_name NVARCHAR(128),
            job_enabled BIT,
            job_description NVARCHAR(MAX),
            job_start_step_id INT,
            job_category_id INT,
            job_owner_sid VARBINARY(85),
            notify_level_eventlog INT,
            notify_level_email INT,
            notify_level_netsend INT,
            notify_level_page INT,
            notify_email_operator_id INT,
            notify_netsend_operator_id INT,
            notify_page_operator_id INT,
            delete_level INT,
            job_date_created DATETIME,
            job_date_modified DATETIME,
            job_version_number INT,
            schedule_id INT,
            schedule_next_run_date INT,
            step_id INT,
            step_name NVARCHAR(128),
            step_subsystem NVARCHAR(128),
            step_command NVARCHAR(MAX),
            step_flags INT,
            step_additional_parameters NVARCHAR(MAX),
            step_cmdexec_success_code INT,
            step_on_success_action INT,
            step_on_success_step_id INT,
            step_on_fail_action INT,
            step_on_fail_step_id INT,
            step_server NVARCHAR(128),
            step_database_name NVARCHAR(128),
            step_database_user_name NVARCHAR(128),
            step_retry_attempts INT,
            step_retry_interval INT,
            step_os_run_priority INT,
            step_output_file_name NVARCHAR(4000),
            step_last_run_outcome INT,
            step_last_run_duration INT,
            step_last_run_retries INT,
            step_last_run_date INT,
            step_last_run_time INT,
            step_proxy_id INT,
            category_id INT,
            category_class INT,
            category_type INT,
            category_name NVARCHAR(128),
            server_id INT,
            server_name NVARCHAR(128),
            server_last_run_outcome INT,
            last_outcome_message NVARCHAR(MAX),
            server_last_run_date INT,
            server_last_run_time INT,
            server_last_run_duration INT,
            schedule_name NVARCHAR(128),
            schedule_freq_type INT,
            schedule_originating_server_id INT,
            schedule_owner_sid VARBINARY(85),
            schedule_enabled BIT,
            schedule_freq_interval INT,
            schedule_freq_subday_type INT,
            schedule_freq_subday_interval INT,
            schedule_freq_relative_interval INT,
            schedule_freq_recurrence_factor INT,
            schedule_date_created DATETIME,
            schedule_date_modified DATETIME,
            schedule_active_start_date INT,
            schedule_active_end_date INT,
            schedule_active_start_time INT,
            schedule_active_end_time INT,
            operator_id INT,
            operator_name NVARCHAR(128),
            op_email_address  NVARCHAR(128),
            op_notify_page_operator_name  NVARCHAR(128),
            alerts_id INT,
            alerts_name NVARCHAR(128) ,
            alert_has_notifications INT,
            alerts_database_name NVARCHAR(512),
            message_id INT,
            severity INT,
            delay_between_responses INT
        );
    END;

    -- Insert data
    INSERT INTO [Test_DB1].dbo.JobAgentRestore (
        job_id,
        originating_server_id,
        job_name,
        owner_name,
        job_enabled,
        job_description,
        job_start_step_id,
        job_category_id,
        job_owner_sid,
        notify_level_eventlog,
        notify_level_email,
        notify_level_netsend,
        notify_level_page,
        notify_email_operator_id,
        notify_netsend_operator_id,
        notify_page_operator_id,
        delete_level,
        job_date_created,
        job_date_modified,
        job_version_number,
        schedule_id,
        schedule_next_run_date,
        step_id,
        step_name,
        step_subsystem,
        step_command,
        step_flags,
        step_additional_parameters,
        step_cmdexec_success_code,
        step_on_success_action,
        step_on_success_step_id,
        step_on_fail_action,
        step_on_fail_step_id,
        step_server,
        step_database_name,
        step_database_user_name,
        step_retry_attempts,
        step_retry_interval,
        step_os_run_priority,
        step_output_file_name,
        step_last_run_outcome,
        step_last_run_duration,
        step_last_run_retries,
        step_last_run_date,
        step_last_run_time,
        step_proxy_id,
        category_id,
        category_class,
        category_type,
        category_name,
        server_id,
        server_name,
        server_last_run_outcome,
        last_outcome_message,
        server_last_run_date,
        server_last_run_time,
        server_last_run_duration,
        schedule_name,
        schedule_freq_type,
        schedule_originating_server_id,
        schedule_owner_sid,
        schedule_enabled,
        schedule_freq_interval,
        schedule_freq_subday_type,
        schedule_freq_subday_interval,
        schedule_freq_relative_interval,
        schedule_freq_recurrence_factor,
        schedule_date_created,
        schedule_date_modified,
        schedule_active_start_date,
        schedule_active_end_date,
        schedule_active_start_time,
        schedule_active_end_time,
        operator_id,
        operator_name,
        op_email_address,
        op_notify_page_operator_name,
        alerts_id,
        alerts_name,
        alert_has_notifications,
        alerts_database_name,
        message_id,
        severity,
        delay_between_responses
    )
    SELECT
        j.job_id,
        j.originating_server_id,
        j.name AS job_name,
        SUSER_SNAME(j.owner_sid) as owner_name ,
        j.enabled AS job_enabled,
        j.description AS job_description,
        j.start_step_id AS job_start_step_id,
        j.category_id AS job_category_id,
        j.owner_sid, 
        j.notify_level_eventlog,
        j.notify_level_email,
        j.notify_level_netsend,
        j.notify_level_page,
        j.notify_email_operator_id,
        j.notify_netsend_operator_id,
        j.notify_page_operator_id,
        j.delete_level,
        j.date_created AS job_date_created,
        j.date_modified AS job_date_modified,
        j.version_number AS job_version_number,
        js.schedule_id AS schedule_id,
        js.next_run_date AS schedule_next_run_date,
        st.step_id AS step_id,
        st.step_name AS step_name,
        st.subsystem AS step_subsystem,
        st.command AS step_command,
        st.flags AS step_flags,
        st.additional_parameters AS step_additional_parameters,
        st.cmdexec_success_code AS step_cmdexec_success_code,
        st.on_success_action AS step_on_success_action,
        st.on_success_step_id AS step_on_success_step_id,
        st.on_fail_action AS step_on_fail_action,
        st.on_fail_step_id AS step_on_fail_step_id,
        st.server AS step_server,
        st.database_name AS step_database_name,
        st.database_user_name AS step_database_user_name,
        st.retry_attempts AS step_retry_attempts,
        st.retry_interval AS step_retry_interval,
        st.os_run_priority AS step_os_run_priority,
        st.output_file_name AS step_output_file_name,
        st.last_run_outcome AS step_last_run_outcome,
        st.last_run_duration AS step_last_run_duration,
        st.last_run_retries AS step_last_run_retries,
        st.last_run_date AS step_last_run_date,
        st.last_run_time AS step_last_run_time,
        st.proxy_id AS step_proxy_id,
        c.category_id AS category_id,
        c.category_class,
        c.category_type,
        c.name AS category_name,
        sv.server_id AS server_id,
        ss.name AS server_name,
        sv.last_run_outcome AS server_last_run_outcome,
        sv.last_outcome_message,
        sv.last_run_date AS server_last_run_date,
        sv.last_run_time AS server_last_run_time,
        sv.last_run_duration AS server_last_run_duration,
        sch.name AS schedule_name,
        sch.freq_type AS schedule_freq_type,
        sch.originating_server_id AS schedule_originating_server_id,
        sch.owner_sid AS schedule_owner_sid,
        sch.enabled AS schedule_enabled,
        sch.freq_interval AS schedule_freq_interval,
        sch.freq_subday_type AS schedule_freq_subday_type,
        sch.freq_subday_interval AS schedule_freq_subday_interval,
        sch.freq_relative_interval AS schedule_freq_relative_interval,
        sch.freq_recurrence_factor AS schedule_freq_recurrence_factor,
        sch.date_created AS schedule_date_created,
        sch.date_modified AS schedule_date_modified,
        sch.active_start_date AS schedule_active_start_date,
        sch.active_end_date AS schedule_active_end_date,
        sch.active_start_time AS schedule_active_start_time,
        sch.active_end_time AS schedule_active_end_time,
        op.id as operator_id,
        op.name as operator_name,
        op.email_address as op_email_address,
        op.name as op_notify_page_operator_name,
        al.id as alerts_id,
        al.name as alerts_name,
        al.has_notification as alert_has_notifications,
        al.database_name as alerts_database_name,
        al.message_id as message_id,
        al.severity as severity,
        al.delay_between_responses as delay_between_responses
    FROM 
        sdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS js ON j.job_id = js.job_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysschedules AS sch ON js.schedule_id = sch.schedule_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS st ON j.job_id = st.job_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.syscategories AS c ON j.category_id = c.category_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysjobservers AS sv ON j.job_id = sv.job_id
    LEFT JOIN
        sys.database_principals AS dp ON j.owner_sid = dp.sid
    LEFT JOIN
        sys.servers  as ss ON ss.server_id = sv.server_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysoperators AS op ON op.id = j.notify_email_operator_id
    LEFT JOIN
        msdb.dbo.sysalerts AS al ON al.category_id = c.category_id;

I has parameters and try with
SELECT [job_id],[originating_server_id],[job_name],[owner_name],[job_enabled],[job_description],[category_id],[category_class],[category_type],[category_name],[server_id]
FROM [Test_DB1].[dbo].[JobAgentRestore] WHERE job_name = 'Test_job_3'


job_id =5F58B842-020E-472D-BBF1-AA005A3F9872, originating_server_id=0, job_name=Test_job_3, owner_name='TestUser2', job_enabled =1, job_description = 'TEst_job_3', category_id=10, category_class =1, category_type=1, category_name='REPL-Distribution', server_id =0
You can also see the same in the picture
enter image description here
and I got data @category_id = 10 and @category_name = 'REPL distribution';
-- Define the parameters
DECLARE @category_id INT;
DECLARE @category_name NVARCHAR(128);

-- Set the values for the parameters
SET @category_id = 10; -- Example value for the category ID
SET @category_name = 'REPL distribution'; -- Example value for the category name

-- Run the stored procedure
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_verify_category_identifiers @category_name, @category_id;


Unfortunately, four parameters are expected here, instead of two and the first two parameters, I don't know how to do it in code
I tried to create a script of jobagent when creating new job agent and got this code
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Test_job-agent_2', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
    @notify_level_email=2, 
    @notify_level_page=2, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'Test_job Agent 2', 
    @category_name=N'Data Collector', 
    @owner_login_name=N'TestUser2', 
    @notify_email_operator_name=N'Operator', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
SELECT @jobId


and here is my code
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job    
    @job_name = @job_name,
    @enabled = @job_enabled,
    @description = @job_description,
    @start_step_id = @job_start_step_id,
    @category_id = @job_category_id,
    @category_name = @category_name,
    @notify_level_eventlog = @notify_level_eventlog,
    @notify_level_email = @notify_level_email,
    @notify_level_netsend = @notify_level_netsend,
    @notify_level_page = @notify_level_page,
    @delete_level = @delete_level,
    @owner_login_name = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @owner_name) + ',
    @notify_email_operator_name=@operator_name, 
    @notify_page_operator_name=@op_notify_page_operator_name,
    @job_id = @job_id OUTPUT


Someone, why isn't it working?
Thanks
PS
here is screenshot
enter image description here

There is a lot of code here but it is not at all clear what your question is. What "isn't working"? What about it is not doing what you expect? Do you get error messages? If so, what are they?

I don't know, but this line @owner_login_name = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @owner_name) + ', doesn't do what you think it does.

I try with
@owner_login_name = 'TestUser2' , but I got the same error

@Sean Lange, I have shown whole code because I thought probably someone can try it out. You can copy it and check it if someone has already created the script.
I expected that the data from table takes and agent job was restored

Rather, you should be taking the time to identify exactly where the failure is occurring, and focusing on that, @randia .

Also the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?. Creating a procedure with that prefix in msdb seems more unwise; it's rare to need user objects in system databases, but with that prefix it implies it's a built-in procedure.

Hello @Thom A , I didn't really understand, do you mean that I created new procedure with sp_prefix? I didn't create new procedure, I just used this procedure. Am I not allowed to use this procedure? Should I this procedure copy and save with different names?

Do you mean you have scripted a sql server agent job and are now trying to create it and getting errors?

@siggemanen, yes , I did

You are ALTERing sp_verify_category_identifiers, which suggests it's a user procedure. If it's not, and it is built-in then don't try to ALTER it.

When you call sp_add_job you must provide either @category_id or category_name parameter value, not both. so just use NULL for the category_name. Don't call verify proc yourself.
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job    
    @job_name = @job_name,
    @enabled = @job_enabled,
    @description = @job_description,
    @start_step_id = @job_start_step_id,
    @category_id = @job_category_id,
    @category_name = NULL, -- <---- Changed!
    @notify_level_eventlog = @notify_level_eventlog,
    @notify_level_email = @notify_level_email,
    @notify_level_netsend = @notify_level_netsend,
    @notify_level_page = @notify_level_page,
    @delete_level = @delete_level,
    @owner_login_name = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(128), @owner_name) + ',
    @notify_email_operator_name=@operator_name, 
    @notify_page_operator_name=@op_notify_page_operator_name,
    @job_id = @job_id OUTPUT


I changed,
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
@job_name = @job_name,
@enabled = 1,--@job_enabled,
@description = @job_description,
@start_step_id =1,
@category_name = @category_name,
@owner_login_name  = @owner_name ,
@notify_level_eventlog = 2,
@notify_level_email = 0,
@notify_level_netsend = 0,
@notify_level_page =  @notify_level_page,
@delete_level = 0,
@job_id = @job_id OUTPUT
Select @job_id
I got different error messages:
Cannot add, update, or delete a job (or its steps or schedules) that originated from an MSX server. 

and what happened? :)

I got different error messages: Cannot add, update, or delete a job (or its steps or schedules) that originated from an MSX server.

I saw on internet that there was a suggestion to rename originating_server to sysjobs. unfortunately there is only column 'originating_server_id', no column 'originating_server'

are you sure you didn't pass originating_server as 0? it should really be NULL if originated server isn't in use. I think the main problem of your approach is that you cannot just select values from the sysjobs tables and blindly pass them to procedures

Yes, I'm sure I checked, you can see it on the screenshot. I selected the dates
https://i.sstatic.net/IYf0HTPW.jpg
